# I got Error while using UITableView as 'setText:' is deprecated

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I got Error while using UITableView as  'setText:' is deprecated in line cell.text=cellvalue
Please anyone can how to fix this?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)atable cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [atable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    NSString *cellValue = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.text = cellValue; //Error 'setText:' is deprecated 

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`cell.textLabel.text = @"Value"`

Comment: omg I am so stupid, I kept putting cell.textLabel just like that but I forgot to put .text at the end, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Because Apple added the Subtitle style to the table view cells, you need to use:

```
[cell.textLabel setText:@"String"];
```

instead.

Comment: If you want to use the subtitle, change initWithFrame:CGRectZero to initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle. Set the subtitle text using [cell.detailTextLabel setText:@"String"];

Comment: How to restrict the tables? i have only 5 cell data. I need to restrict the count of rows to 5...

Comment: If you have one section, use the numberOfRowsInSection protocol method as described here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource

Comment: To get out of the (apparently bad: http://www.cimgf.com/2008/07/08/a-case-against-dot-syntax/) habit of using dot notation you can use the following: `[[cell textLabel] setText:@"String"];`